# how to remove php "--without-mssql" "--without-pdo-mssql" parameters?

Tags: php, sql-server, windows

i want connect to mssql server with php. i have installed "Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server" and added some lines in extension part of php.ini. but in phpinfo there wasn't any mssql info. only "--without-mssql" "--without-pdo-mssql" parameters in Configure Command.

i am using windows 7 and iis7.5

i checked phpnifo. Loaded Configuration File C:\Program Files\PHP\php.ini

everthing seems correct in there

Comment: Where are you installing php from (eg WampServer) and which webserver is it running under (eg Apache, IIS or nginx)?

Comment: The which php source question is vital to understand your issue and how to resolve it.

Comment: You might have more than one php.ini file for a single installation of php. On my Linux box, for example, I have three. Make sure the one IIS loaded is the one you edited. Look for "Loaded Configuration File" in phpinfo(). Also read the [Windows notes](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php) here.